# What is this error and why this doesn't happen when I don't use library like a code instead like an aar?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a library in android, and I test it in the app by two ways, the first one, with code, and the second one with the aar file.

Of course, I test all the library in the app with code version, after this, I try to test the 
 app with the aar.

But when execute the app wit the aar, I get following error

> 2019-11-27 10:44:19.795 26687-26687/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: apps, PID: 26687
>       java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver.onCreate(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)"
>           at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:34)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
>           at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
>           at SDK.initSDK(SourceFile:15)
>           at SDK.initSDK(SourceFile:13)
>           at apps.SApplication.onCreate(SApplication.java:20)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5885)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:200)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

The code in SourceFile:15 and 13, are only imports.

Whi I am getting this error, if the library works perfectly with the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Late answer, but suddenly someone will come in handy.

Seems like you are implementing `DefaultLifecycleObserver` somewhere and not overriding `DefaultLifecycleObserver`'s methods.

Just override **ALL** `DefaultLifecycleObserver`'s methods and remove `super` call from them. It should work just fine

Comment: Thank you! I faced the very same issue!! This must be an AndroidX library bug, right?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194289155#comment21

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your min sdk version from 21 to 24 can work around this problem